# What's the most common way of putting configuration options in a front-end application?

Tags: javascript, configuration

To give an example, I want to add the Google+ sign in button to my web app. This button requires my consumer key, and a couple of other configuration options. Just Hardcoding this into the html doesn't seem like a good idea, because you'd have to look for it in the code to change it. I also need this information on the backend, so I have it stored in a JSON configuration file. I see two ways of getting the configuration to the front end:

- fetching the config options using JSON
- inject configuration options at build time

For the second option, I'd add a search/replace action to my gulpfile, and replace any occurrence of `<config:KEY>` with the configuration value of `KEY`.

The second option seems better, because you don't have to make an extra request, but I was wondering if there's a standard way to do it.

Just to clarify: the front end is entirely served as static files, so no way to inject them while rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach, normally coupled with a rails backend, is to generate a javascript file `config.js` that add the required settings and keys to a global object.

With rails I have config.js.erb, that loads my environment variables. So you can use grunt or something as a build process to support this.

Answer (score 0):

For people looking for a more general answer, check out the answer to [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/211533/how-do-you-handle-deployment-configuration-of-your-thick-browser-html-javascrip).